# How to run a macro in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, macros

This is a silly question but spent the last 20 minutes or so browsing through google results and the menus of Netbeans. Under edit there is a start and stop macro recording but after saving the macro I can't seem to find how to run it.

Didn't assign a keyboard short cut to it assuming I can select to run a named macro from the menu somewhere but other than start/stop recording I can't find anything that'll list a macro so I can run it.

Comment: I've run into the same thing with Netbeans 8. It's crazy that to use a macro you first have to assign a keystroke to it.

Answer (score 7):

I have been googeling for a while too, and I could not find much. You can access to the key map and configure the shortcut for your macros. (Tools->Options->Key map). The macros can be accessed in the editor (Tools->Options->Editor)

There is another thread where I found it: [Activating text editing macros on Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630690/activating-text-editing-macros-on-netbeans)

Answer (score 7):

you need to record macro first


go to - **edit**

hit on - **start macro recording** 

 < write code which you want to add in macro >

after writing code - **stop recording macros** 


 then a popup box will appear, you have to set name and a shortcut key for that macro and that's it.

 you can use that macro typing the shortcut key.

[more info](http://www.dalondon.com/blog/how-create-custom-shortcuts-netbeans)

Answer (score 3):

Record another macro - this time assign it to a keystroke by clicking the Set Shortcut button in the dialog box. You will also see your previous macros when you do - and you can assign a shortcut to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change macro `"Upload"` for `'CTRL+s'`
because in default its assigned to `"Save as"` (`ctrl+s`) and it doesn't upload the file while saving it.
Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

go to the menu and click 'add shortcut' ;)

you create your own key shortcut which will start the macro.